# Angular Get method returns an Undefined instead of object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, get

I am an Angular beginner and I've made a service and made all the set up so that the Get method works on a JSON file and it worked! but the problem is whenever I want to access to the data inside the JSON file it tells me that it is undefined, and I want to use it as an object in the ts file.
It works when using data biding like this `{{stats | JSON}}`, but I couldn't use it in the TS. can I convert this 'undefined' to a simple object?

```
stats: any;

constructor(private statsData: StatDataService) {
    this.statsData.GetEmbedded().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.stats = data;
    });
  }
```

`

[image]

for example I can't use `stats.preOrders[0]`

Comment: Can you please add the html's view too? It seems you are trying to access this data when is not available.

Comment: As already noted, your data is not going to be accessible right away, because `GetEmbedded()` returns an *asynchronous* observable, which means `this.stats` is going to be `undefined` until the observable completes.

Comment: what should I do then Please?

Answer (score 0):

To better understand the situation, let's create an example.

*example.component.ts*

```
interface Statistics {
    median: number;
    average: number;
}

export class Example {

    // stats is undefined until GetEmbedded() fires
    stats?: Statistics;

    constructor(private statsData: StatDataService) {
        this.statsData.GetEmbedded().subscribe((stats: Statistics) => {
            this.stats = stats;
        });
      }
}
```

*example.component.html*

```html
<div>The median is: {{ stats.median }}</div>
```

Why will this example result in an error? Your variable `stats` initially is undefined, so it will not have any properties. `GetEmbedded()` will take some milliseconds to fire but in the same time, the template already tries to access `stats.median`.

One option to solve this problem would be to check if the variable `stats` is not undefined and if it is not, access the properties you need.

*example.component.html*

```html
<div *ngIf="stats">The median is: {{ stats.median }}</div>
```